# Google Chrome font aliasing issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

Is there any solution to prevent the aliasing that occurs to fonts when shown in Chrome but not in Firefox?

What would be best is a site-based solution that shows correctly for all visitors.

Comment: There is `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` but that doesn't works well. I can't see any difference.

Comment: Well what does work well?

Comment: You can try with that.

Comment: What platform are you talking about? The fonts on Chrome OS X look nicely antialiased to me...

Comment: It depends on the font, but if font is antialiased in FF, then must be Chrome.

Comment: Here is one strange thing I've noticed. If you use **any** CSS3 filter, that will make font antialiased! So try with `-webkit-filter: opacity(1);`. Result - font will be antialiased, but blurred a bit.

Comment: Is this about fonts included with `@font-face` ?

Comment: Check this out and tell me what you see: http://developed-web.com/  I'd say the "Coming Soon" is pretty aliased in google chrome (win 8) while being perfectly fine looking in Firefox.

Comment: this article may help http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/265/font-face-loaded-on-windows-look-really-bad-which-fonts-are-you-using-that-rend

Comment: Looks a bit different in Chrome. You can though try with -webkit-filter I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
```

Or you can play also with the `text-shadow` or add color to the `stroke` above.

```
text-shadow: 0.0em 0.0em 0.07em rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```